# Close menu after clicking the menu link

Tags: javascript, html

Here have a mobile menu- http://themepack.net/aaa/noar

When you click on the menu link(http://prntscr.com/ez69fm) it's going to the section but the menu is still open. **I need - it should close after clicking the menu link.**

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div class="super-container">
        <div class="slide-container">
            <div class="stripe toggle-nav js-nav">
                <span><a href="#" class="header-lang">ENG</a></span>
                <div class="hamburger-box">                         
                    <!-- <span>Menu</span> -->
                    <div class="bun top"></div>
                    <div class="meat"></div>
                    <div class="bun bottom"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-wrap">
                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#section0">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section1">BRANDING + ID VISUAL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section2">PRODUTOS DIGITAIS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section3">EXPERIÊNCIA DE MARCA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section4">MATERIAL GRÁFICO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section5">CONTATO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section6">MINDSET NOAR</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ENGLISH</a></li>
                        <li class="social-li">
                            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/estanoar"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                            <a href="https://www.behance.net/ESTANOAR"><i class="fa fa-behance"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end super-container -->
</div>
```

I've used below JS code for the menu open/close

```
  var burger = $(".hamburger-box");
  var overlay = $("#overlay");

  burger.on("click", function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $('.js-nav').parent().find('.menu').toggleClass('active');
    overlay.toggle();
  });
```

I've tried with some jQuery click function and followed some StackOverFlow old questions, but still I'm unable to figure out it.

Can any body to help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the click event to the links and let the link trigger the close button.

```
$('.menu ul li a').on("click", function (e) {
  burger.click();
});
```

Comment: Be careful firing events on other elements. That button might have some other bindings that could result in an unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Same way you toggle it when you press the burger button.
The code needs to be on a function, to be [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

```
var toggleMenu = function () {
  var burger = $(".hamburger-box");
  var overlay = $("#overlay");
  var menu = $('.js-nav').parent().find('.menu');

  burger.toggleClass("active");
  menu.toggleClass('active');
  overlay.toggle();
}

$(".hamburger-box, .js-nav a").on("click", toggleMenu);
```

The important part is `$(".hamburger-box, .js-nav a")` where you also bind the event to the links of the menu, and therefore the menu get closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
var burger = ".hamburger-box",
    overlay = "#overlay",
    menu = ".menu",
    menuLink = menu + " a";

function toogleMenu(){
  $(burger).toggleClass("active");
  $(menu).toggleClass('active');
  $(overlay).toggle();
}

$(burger + ', ' + menuLink).click(toogleMenu);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used it and it's working :)

```
$('.menu ul li a').on("click", function (e) {
    burger.click().removeClass("active");
});
```

Thanks everybody for their valuable comment.